# How to change the language of the UI in Alfresco installed on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: alfresco

I've installed Alfresco Community Edition v201707-5 in the Google Cloud. The language of the user interface is Russian. I want to change it into English. The [documentation](https://docs.alfresco.com/cloud/tasks/profile-language-cloud.html) says you can do it in the user profile. It doesn't work for me.

According to the page above, first you need to select "My profile" menu item.

[image: Amin page of Alfresco]

Thereafter the profile page will open, which looks like shown below in my case.

[image: My profile page]

There must be a page titled "Language" here. But I don't see it.

How can I change the language of the user interface?

Comment: IIRC You get the language that your browser requests. What happens if you change the preferred language in your browser?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks. I changed the browser language and this fixed the problem. If you submit your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an Answer...

Alfresco Share use's the Browser's requested language to pick which language to display. Specifically, the `Accept-Language` header. The highest preference language known to Share that your browser requests will determine the language in Share

So, if you tell your web browser to prefer English over Russian, then Share should switch over too!